# Allow null values in ManyToOne inversed entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

I have this entity:

```
class Brand
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Company
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="brands")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="companies_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $company;

    ...

    /**
     * Set company.
     *
     * @param Company $company
     *
     * @return Brands
     */
    public function setCompany(Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

If I remove the `Company` type-hint from the method signature, I get this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Entity\Brand::setCompany() must be an instance of
>   AppBundleEntity\Company, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 410 and defined

I set the property to `nullable` but I can't remove the object from the data, why? How this can be fixed?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with caching. The error is on the method you said you modified. If you're using something like Zend OPCache, try restarting/disabling it. Seems like the old class definition is used. Note: you can also do `setCompany(Company $company=null)` to preserve type safety and allow nulls.

Comment: @Anonymous that works, I just restarted my web server and clear the cache (I was cleared previously) and all is good, thanks, BTW, how do I know if I am using any kind of cache?

Comment: I'll write a full answer is a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with caching. The error is on the method you said you modified. If you're using something like Zend OPCache, try restarting/disabling it. Seems like the old class definition is used.

**Note:** you can also do `setCompany(Company $company=null)` to preserve type safety and allow nulls [(PHP 5.1+)](http://3v4l.org/b3gXW).

---

The easiest way to check what you have enabled is to check your `phpinfo()` output. If you're using OPCache, you'll see it in there. Here is the configuration for my dev environment (in `php.ini`):

```
[OPCACHE]
zend_extension="php_opcache.dll"
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
```

The last option is the important one - it re-reads any files that were updated. In production you would want to set it to zero (and `opcache.revalidate_freq` to zero) to reduce disk access. [See more settings here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php).

While things like APC still work, the built-in Zend OPCache is the way to go on PHP 5.5+, so I recommend switching if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify setCompany method as given below

```
public function setCompany(Company $company=null)
{
    $this->company = $company;
    return $this;
}
```